# ASP.NET Core : moving data from one table into another

Tags: html, asp.net-core

I'm currently developing an e-commerce website using ASP.NET Core. I'm trying to move data from the `Products` table into the `Items` table using a button press so that the data in the items table can be presented on the basket page. Any help would be appreciated.

The relevant button is using the `asp-action=AddToCart`:

```
<div class="card-body">
    <h3 class="card-title">@product.Name</h3>
    <svg class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" width="100%" >
        <img float="left" width="450" height="450" src="~/assets/Clothing/@product.ProductImage" alt="Image of @product.Name" />
    </svg>
    
    <p class="card-text">@product.Description</p>
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
        <div class="btn-group">
            @if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
            {
                <a class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" asp-page="/UpdateProductInfo"
                   asp-route-id="@product.Id">Update</a> 
            }
                                
            <a class="btn" asp-action="AddToCart">Add to Cart</a>
            <p class="float-right card-text" >£@product.Price</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

C#

```
[BindProperty]
public Item Items { get; set; }

public IActionResult addToCart()
{
    _db.Items.Add(Items);
    _db.SaveChanges();
    return Page();
}
```

product.cs model

```
public class Product
{
    public String Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Name")]
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String Description { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Price")]
    public int Price { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ProductImage")]
    public String ProductImage { get; set; }
    public String ProductImageName { get; set; }
}
```

Item.cs model

```
public class Item
{
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("Name")]
    public String Name { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Price")]
    public int Price { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ProductImage")]
    public String ProductImage { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: please also include the code of your models.

Comment: Whether your application is a MVC application or Razor page application? Based on your code, to pass the product to Item, when click the "Add to Cart" button, you should pass the selected product or its primary key to the `addToCart` method. If your application is a MVC application, you could send the primary key via the route, change the code as below: `<a class="btn" asp-action="AddToCart" asp-route-id="@product.Id">Add to Cart</a>` and `public IActionResult addToCart(int id)`, and then, in the addToCart method, based on the id to find the related product, according it to insert a new Item.

Comment: its a razor page application.

Answer (score 0):

item class must be like this :

```cs
    public class Item
    {
        [Key]
        public int ItemId { get; set; }

        public Product Product { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Product")]
        public int ProductId { get; set; }

        public String ProductImage { get; set; }
    }
```

and your product class :

```cs
    public class Product
    {
        [Key]
        public int ProductId { get; set; }

        public string Name{ get; set; }

        public int Price { get; set; }

        public int Description{ get; set; }

        public string ProductImage { get; set; }

        public string ProductImageName { get; set; }

    }
```

it was a (single to single) relationship between two tables

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to move data from the Products table into the Items table
> using a button press so that the data in the items table can be
> presented on the basket page. Any help would be appreciated.

From your description, I assume in the main page, you are listed the Products and each row of the product will have an "Add to Cart" button, after clicking it, it will add the selected Product to the Item table, right?

Since your application is an Asp.net core Razor Page application, for the "Add to Cart" button, you could use the handler method to transfer the route parameter to the method, and then add the selected product to Item table. Refer the following sample:

Model:

```
public class Product
{
    public String Id { get; set; } 
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String Description { get; set; } 
    public int Price { get; set; } 
    public String ProductImage { get; set; }
    public String ProductImageName { get; set; }
}
public class Item
{
    [Key] 
    public String Name { get; set; } 
    public int Price { get; set; } 
    public String ProductImage { get; set; }

}
```

ProductIndex.cshtml:

```
@page
@model RazorPageSample.Pages.ProductIndexModel
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <form method="post">
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr><th colspan="5">Product Table</th></tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            Product ID
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Product Name
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Description
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Price
                        </th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach (var item in Model.Products)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @item.Id
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @item.Name
                            </td>
                            <td class="text-right">
                                @item.Description
                            </td>
                            <td class="text-right">
                                £@item.Price
                            </td>
                            <td class="text-right"> 
                                <button asp-page-handler="AddToCart" class="btn btn-primary" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Add to Cart</button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
            </form>
    </div>
       <div class="col-md-6">
        <table class="table">
            <thead><tr><th colspan="5">Item Table</th></tr>
                <tr> 
                    <th>
                        Item Name
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Price
                    </th> 
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @if (Model.Items !=null && Model.Items.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (var item in Model.Items)
                    {
                        <tr> 
                            <td>
                                @item.Name
                            </td>
                            <td class="text-right">
                                £@item.Price
                            </td>
                            <td class="text-right"> 
                            </td> 
                        </tr>
                    }
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

ProductIndex.cshtml.cs:

```
public class ProductIndexModel : PageModel
{
    //Here I use a DataRepository to set the initial data.
    private readonly IDataRepository _repository;
    public ProductIndexModel(IDataRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }
    [BindProperty]
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; } //item list.
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; } // product list
    public void OnGet()
    {
        Products = _repository.GetProducts();
    }
     
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAddToCartAsync(string id)
    {
        // use session to store the items. 
        // you could directly store the new item into database. in this scenario, you could query the database and get the existing items.
        if (HttpContext.Session.Get<List<Item>>("_Items") != default)
        {
            Items = (List<Item>)HttpContext.Session.Get<List<Item>>("_Items");
        }
        if (id != null)
        {
            var product = _repository.GetProducts().Where(c => c.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
            Item newitem = new Item()
            {
                Name = product.Name,
                Price = product.Price
            };
            Items.Add(newitem);
            HttpContext.Session.Set<List<Item>>("_Items", Items);
        }
        //reset the Products. 
        Products = _repository.GetProducts();
        return Page();
    }
}
```

The screenshot as below:

[image]

More detail information, you could refer the following links:

[Handler Methods in Razor Pages](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/handler-methods)

[Write a basic form](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#write-a-basic-form)

[Session and state management in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

[Note]If you want to use Session to store the Object,after configuring your application use session, remember to add SessionExtensions.